# JSON Schema — Validate against multiple nullable schemas?

Tags: openapi, jsonschema, ajv

I'm trying to validate `null` against the schema below:

```js
{
  oneOf: [
    { type: "string", nullable: true },
    { type: "number", nullable: true },
  ]
}
```

I was expecting the validation to be a success, but it wasn't. Without `oneOf` (so with just one schema but still with `nullable: true`) the validation passes.

Here is my sample code:

```js
import Ajv from "ajv";
const ajv = new Ajv();
const schema = {
  oneOf: [
    { type: "string", nullable: true },
    { type: "number", nullable: true },
  ],
};

const data = null;
const validate = ajv.compile(schema);
const valid = validate(data);
if (!valid) {
  console.log(validate.errors);
} else {
  console.log("Validation Success");
}
```

Im using `Ajv@8.11.0` and `open api specification 3.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `oneOf` to `anyOf`. The reason it fails is because `oneOf` requires the data to match **exactly one** schema, however `null` will match both.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add the {type: "null"} in your JSON schema as one of the options. For more information, see: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/null.html

Comment: im using openapi specification 3.0, where null type is removed @Dvir